# Lookup on object of indeterminate type

Tags: f#, type-inference

I'm trying to figure out why this doesn't compile.

```
type A() =
  member __.M(f:DateTime -> seq<int>) = ()
  member __.M(f:DateTime -> obj) = ()

let a = A()
a.M(fun d -> seq [d.Year]) // 'd' is indeterminate type
```

If I remove the second overload or add a type annotation to `d`, it does. Is it because some aspect of overload resolution occurs prior to type checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, basically overloads make type inference hard.  In this case, it seems like you're hoping that the compiler will do some sort of generalization of the types `DateTime -> seq<int>` and `DateTime -> obj` to get `DateTime -> ?` and then proceed from there, but I don't think it ever does that kind of "anti-unification".

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, but wondered why the type annotation clears things up. I suppose it allows it to proceed with analyzing `f`'s return type, and thus find a match?

Comment: @Daniel - I think that's right - if you add an annotation then the inner lambda has type `DateTime -> seq<int>` and inference can pick the overload correctly; if you remove one of the overloads then `M` is unique and type information can flow into the lambda to constrain `d`'s type.